# adding echo deletes textareas

Tags: php

When adding my echo statements, the textarea boxes dissapear. This is the selection of code:

```
<?php
$rs_settings = mysql_query("select * from thesis where id='$_SESSION[user_id]'");


        ?>

 <br><?php  while ($row_settings = mysql_fetch_array($rs_settings)) {?>
  <form action="thesis.php" method="post" name="regForm" id="regForm" >
    <div class="forms">

           Title of Proposed Thesis<span class="required">*</span>
      <textarea name="thesis_name" type="text" id="thesis_name" size="600"><?php echo
 $row_settings['thesis_Name']; ?></textarea>

            Abstract<span class="required">*</span>
          <textarea name="abstract" type="text" id="abstract" size="600"><?php echo 
$row_settings['abstract']; ?></textarea> 



      <?php } ?>
```

Does anyone know which piece of code is cauisng this?

Comment: Could you confirm whether you have short_tags enabled? Some of your code uses <?php and other parts use <?

Comment: Could you also confirm how many rows you (expect to) have returned in $row_settings? It's possible (though, I admit, unlikely) that you're ending up with more than one <textarea> element with the same ID (i.e. more than one with id="thesis_Name" and more than one with id="abstract").

Comment: If you're able to post the resulting 'view source' output (for that part of the page) that might help as well. If you're familiar with jsfiddle, that would be ideal.

Comment: view source doesnt show any of the code I have posted. Stops after the page title

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is incorrect. `<textarea>` doesn't have a `value` attribute. You are supposed to place the value between an opening and closing `<textarea>` tags.

```
 <textarea name="abstract" type="text" id="abstract" size="600"><?php echo $row_settings['abstract']; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: ...but if the textareas really disappear, it's possibly because notices are emitted inside the `value` attribute of the `<textarea>` tag. Wrong syntax (only) would cause the content to not show up, not the control itself to vanish.

Comment: Thanks I have changed it to the above, but they still don't appear

Comment: @user1296762 Your code from your question was missing `>` on both `textarea` blocks. Make sure your new code isn't as well.

Comment: Can you update your question to show us the HTML your code now produces so we can see what it looks like?

Comment: `<div class="forms">` is in your loop but never closed.